# Table Indexing not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make staff listing to work faster on the basis of client selection. To do that I have created an index for client_id field.

I have attached the screenshot of table structure and index structure.

This is the SQL query I have used for the selection.

```
SELECT staff_client_id,staff_id,staff_full_name from kr_staffs where staff_client_id=2 AND staff_status='active'
```

But the speed of the query is the same without index.

This is my table structure

[image]

This is table index structure

[image]

Comment: How many rows are in this table? How are you measuring performance?  I think something else might be afoot: for example, if your table has a few thousand rows and a query is taking 100ms to complete then it's likely to be a networking issue between the client and database server.

Comment: @Dai 2000 rows in the table..and there is no problem in the network.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the query execution plan to confirm that the index is being used. You can refer to EXPLAIN http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html.

Can you instead measure time taken for the following query (with and without index):

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM kr_staffs WHERE staff_client_id=2 AND staff_status='active'

Comment: I tried your query with out index and with index. Both of them took the same time.

Comment: @JohnMathew If there are many records with staff_client_id = 2, then the query optimizer might decide to do full table scan instead of the unclustered index. If index is used, then each record must be looked up (for checking staff_status or fetching data) and this might be costlier than doing the table scan directly.